# Warning (in R): "ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable"

Tags: r, anova, error-message

I have the data:

```
numbers <- c(0.176, 0.005, 0.022, 0.016, 0.036, 0.095, 0.069 )
Inds <- as.factor(c("P06", "P07", "P08", "P09", "P10", "P12", "P13") )
```

and am trying to test for differences in `numbers` as a function of `Inds`.  The numbers are proportions of an events success for each individual.  With `Inds` specified as a factor, I am trying conduct an ANOVA using `aov()` (below)

```
anova(aov(numbers ~ Inds))
```

which results in the warning (below)

```
Analysis of Variance Table
Response: numbers
          Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Inds       6 0.021743 0.0036238               
Residuals  0 0.000000                         
Warning message:
In anova.lm(aov(numbers ~ Inds)) :
  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable
```

Any suggestions (changes in code or theoretical mistakes) would be appreciated.

Comment: This is really a statistical question rather than a programming question.  If you want to do an ANOVA you need more than one observation per group.  You *can* test equality of proportions with a single observation per group (e.g. with a binomial GLM or with a Pearson X^2 contingency table analysis), but you will need to have the total number of individuals per group, not just the proportions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker for your suggestions.  Sounds like Exchange might be a better forum.  I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: The other point to consider is that using proportions as a continuous variable obscures the underlying data which of necessity are counts. (So still evidence that you DO need statistical help.)

Comment: the F-test is essentially a ratio of standard deviations. Every factor has only one observation. Your standard deviation is zero. You get a test-statistic of infinity making it ridiculous to compare variances because there is no variance in your sample.

Comment: I first read the title as implying that R can't be trusted here. But R's reaction to the command is undoubtedly reasonable. If anything it understates that the user asked a question that can't be answered. Otherwise put, the warning is a warning to the user, not a warning about R.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The F-test is essentially a ratio of standard deviations. Every factor has only one observation in your sample data. Your standard deviation is zero. You get a test-statistic of zero because one cannot compare variances in your sample because there is no variance in your sample.

There is variance across factors but not within a factor.